# Sitecore user rights for command

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have next situation:
I should allow to see "Add Rendering" button in Page Edit mode for some user.

I go to Content Editor and copy some item (button) which user can see in Page Edit mode.
I go to Access Viewer and see that user have ability to see this button. 
Then I login to Page Edit mode with this user and I can see two  buttons. I switch back to Content editor and change only command("Click" field) for button. E.g.: from "webedit:logout" to "webedit:newrendering".
I go to Access Viewer and check again that user have ability to see this button.

But when I login to Page Edit mode with this user I can see only one button. (But admin user still see 2 buttons).

It seems that there is some way to set user rights directly to command.

How it could be done?

Sitecore version 6.5.0.

Comment: Your question is poorly worded and hard to comprehend. Can you revise it to make it more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'webedit:newrendering' command overrides the QueryState method which affects the command accessibility.
Granting access rights '/sitecore/system/Settings/Security/Policies/Page Editor/Can Design' item in core database solves this problem.